# My variable that I'm getting from a text file is not defined

Tags: python

My first set of code where I wrote the code into the text file is:

```
water = open ('water.txt','w')

for i in range(4):
    account_number = int(input("Enter account number:"))
    type = input('enter R for residential, B for business: ')
    gallons = int(input('Enter number of gallons:'))
    water.write(str(account_number) + " " + type +" " + str(gallons) + "\n")

water.close()
```

The code where I read and calculate the data from text file is:

```
output = open('water.txt', 'r')
for line in output:
    words =line.strip().split()
    account_number = words[0]
    type = words[1]
    gallons = words[2]
    price = 0
    if type =='R':
        if gallons <= '6000':
            price = 0.005 * gallons
        else:
            price = 0.007 * gallons
    else:
        if type =='B':
            if gallons <= '8000':
               price = 0.007 * gallons
            else:
                price = 0.008 * gallons
                print (price)
print('Account Number %s Water charge: $%.2f'% (account_number,price))
output.close()
```

However the `account_number` and the `price` variables are not defined and I can't see the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "not defined"? Was there a traceback message? If so. post that full message so we can see the error and the line that failed.

Comment: That implies that `output` is empty. But is the `print()` supposed to be in the loop? That would make more sense. In any case, what's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. For debugging help, please provide a [mre] with less code, example input, expected output, and the full error message. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Without traceback, it would be difficult to debug, do share the same, follow the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask guidelines, to ask questions with more clarity.

Comment: All works fine for me, as i can see, you just have to indent last print (to be in the loop) and to float(gallons)?

Comment: FYI, the word `type` just happens to be a built-in function and thus probably not a great choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

words are string, so you have to convert them to float or integer for comparsions. I converted to float. Second you cannot compare with string `'6000'`. See below the answer.

```
water = open ('water.txt','w')

for i in range(4):
    account_number = int(input("Enter account number:"))
    type = input('enter R for residential, B for business: ')
    gallons = int(input('Enter number of gallons:'))
    water.write(str(account_number) + " " + type +" " + str(gallons) + "\n")

water.close()


output = open('water.txt', 'r')
for line in output:
    print(line)
    words =line.strip("\n").split(" ")
    print(words)
    account_number = float(words[0]) # converted to float, but can also be integer as well, as int(words[2])
    type = words[1]
    gallons = float(words[2]) # converted to float, but can also be integer as well, as int(words[2])
    price = 0
    if type =='R':
        if gallons <= 6000:  # you cannot compare with string, converted to 6000
            price = 0.005 * gallons
        else:
            price = 0.007 * gallons
    else:
        if type =='B':
            if gallons <= 8000: # you cannot compare with string, converted to 8000
                price = 0.007 * gallons
            else:
                price = 0.008 * gallons
                print (price)

print('Account Number %s Water charge: $%.2f'% (account_number,price))


output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is empty, your loop will not run, and `account_number` and `price` will not be defined. Python can't declare a variable without an assignment which will definitely execute. To fix this, put this line before your loop:

```
account_number = price = None
```

You should probably check to see if one of these variables is still `None` before running the `print` call.